# Seconds Until a Specified Day of the Week

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having some trouble calculating the number of seconds until a specified day of the week.

- For example, calculate the number of seconds until Sunday from the current time in seconds.
- The calculation must be dynamic so it is compatible for every Sunday.

Is there any way to accomplish this without specifying a specific date?

Comment: Sorry, seconds from the current time. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`. See the code example below. Make sure to set the calendar to "gregorian" if you want the correct 7 day week for the US.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

// Just a test line for your benefit.  
NSLog(@"%li %li %li %li",(long)comps.weekday,(long)comps.hour, (long)comps.minute, (long)comps.second);

// I did this kinda fast - check it over good. Will need some sort of if statement in case the current day is Sunday (7)
NSInteger sec = (60 - comps.second) + (60 - comps.minute)*60 + (24 - comps.hour)*3600 + (6 - comps.weekday)*24*60*60;
NSLog(@"%li",sec);
```

You will have to modify this somewhat for your use. For instance if you want the day of the week to be a variable, etc. but this should get you on the right track.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

**EDIT**

See Duncan's remarks below for a better way to actually calculate the seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The NSCalendar class has a whole bunch of methods for this sort of thing. Do a search on "Calendrical calculations" in Xcode for more information.

You'll need a Gregorian NSCalendar (or other type for other calendars like the Chinese, Arabic, Hebrew calendar) NSDates, and NSDateComponents objects.

Look at the method components:fromDate:toDate:options: in particular.

EDIT: That'll teach me to leave an answer unfinished and go do the dishes.

One difference from Dylan's post, though: I would take the current NSDate, convert it to components, then set the day-of-week to the desired future day of week, then convert back to an NSDate, and finally take the difference between the two dates using the NSDate method timeIntervalSinceDate.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that is better way to actually calculate the seconds. I was just trying to give him an example to work from. Anyway, I added a reference to your post in my answer.